# Display charts according to user selection

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I'am using JasperReport4.0 for the reporting and JSF2.0/primefaces , 
I have the following scenario :
The user choose the type of charts that he want to visualize from a page jsf(from a selctbox),I want to know how can I do that ,I mean how can I display dynamically  those charts in the report .
eg: when he choose pie charts I should display pie
    when he choose bar charts I should display bar

Please help me